# Can't install Antispam plugin by CleanTalk in Joomla3.8

Tags: php, joomla3.8, captcha

I'm trying to install . Once the install button is clicked, I keep waiting and nothing happens.

Upon checking the DevTools Console, there are errors stating:

1. Uncaught Reference Error: jedpps-jsoncallback is not defined
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
3. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting'value')

Here's the code that makes an error:

```
Joomla.submitbutton5 = function(a) {

    var b = document.getElementById("adminForm");

    b.install_url.value != "" && b.install_url.value != "http://" 
        ? Joomla.submitbutton4()
        : b.install_url.value == ""
        ? alert(apps_btntxt)
        : (
           apps_is_hathor || jQuery("#appsloading").css("display", "block"),
           b.installtype.value = "web",
           b.submit()
          )
}
```

This is my first time encountering this error.

Comment: I would bring this up with CleanTalk, you don't want to get a quick fix which will be broken again once they roll out an update.

Comment: Joomla 3.8 is a very outdated version of Joomla 3.x. There have been many updates since it's release on 18 September 2017, even some security updates. It's recommended to update at least to the latest 3.10.12 (or even to the current stable version: Joomla 4.x)